# WordPress Как подключить скрипты в head с атрибутом defer

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Не могу разобраться как подключить скрипты в head с атрибутом defer в WordPress.

---

Вот содержимое файла functions.php

```
<?php

function elkino_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'header', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/header.js');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'yandex-map-api', 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'util-calculate-area-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/util.calculateArea.min.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'polylabel-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/polylabel.min.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'newmap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/newmap.js' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'elkino_scripts');

?>
```

Comment: Лучше подключать скрипты в подвале сайта, а не в шапке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого надо использовать такой фильтр:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'script_loader_tag_filter', 10, 3 );
function script_loader_tag_filter( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'yandex-map-api' === $handle ) {
        return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
    }

    return $tag;
}
```

В примере добавляется defer к скрипту yandex.